# Unable to set a value in the drop down using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am having trouble selecting an element from a drop down box.
Here is the div

```
<div class="select ccMonth" id="payflow-form-ccMonth-select">
<select name="expMonth" class="month payflow-form-ccMonth-select   hidden" id="payflow-form-ccMonth-select-select">
<option value="Month">Month</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<span name="expirationMonthSpan">Month</span><ul>
<li data-index="0">Month</li>
<li data-index="1">1</li>
<li data-index="2">2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The div is returned correctly when i run this

```
document.getElementById('payflow-form-ccMonth-select-select');
```

However on Chrome when i try the below, it doesn't set value i want in the drop down box.

```
document.getElementById('payflow-form-ccMonth-select-select').selectedIndex=1;
```

I have also tried to get it in focus first with click() which expands the drop down box but it still won't work.

```
document.getElementById('payflow-form-ccMonth-select-select').click();
document.getElementById('payflow-form-ccMonth-select-select').selectedIndex=1;
```

I have also tried this which did not work either

```
document.getElementById('payflow-form-ccMonth-select-select').value = 1;
```

Any hints on what i may be missing?
Thanks

Comment: Checked Your Code And its Working Check http://jsbin.com/zez/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  var dropdown = document.getElementById('payflow-form-ccMonth-select-select');
  dropdown.options[indexToSelect].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your Code and its working Fine Check [This](http://jsbin.com/zez/3/edit).

The only Problem I can think is that your code is placed in `head` and it get executed before actual page is ready

you can try  **`window.onload`**

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('payflow-form-ccMonth-select-select').selectedIndex= 1;

}
```